# Web dynos keep crashing while trying to deploy my first node.js app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

```
$ foreman start
```

creates a link with my working app
I have a file Called Procfile that contains:

```
web: node server.js
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "socket.io": "*",
    "underscore": "*"
  }
}
```

So I go to start the "dynos" with

```
 $ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... done, now running 1


$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `node server.js`
web.1: restarting 2013/09/27 22:10:44 (~ 34s ago)
```

a little later

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `node server.js`
web.1: crashed 2013/09/27 22:11:49 (~ 10s ago)
```

Any ideas on where I go from here?

EDIT: Here are some logs

```
2013-09-27T12:10:47.177359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2013-09-27T12:10:48.381526+00:00 app[web.1]: Server up and running. Go to http://127.0.0.1:8080
2013-09-27T12:10:48.342939+00:00 app[web.1]: info: socket.io started
2013-09-27T12:11:48.499022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2013-09-27T12:11:48.499325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-27T12:11:49.656186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-27T12:11:49.643225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

EDI: server.js

```
var portx = process.env.PORT;  // This is my addition

var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , http = require("http").createServer(app)
  , io = require("socket.io").listen(http)
  , _ = require("underscore");

var participants = []

app.set("ipaddr", "127.0.0.1");

app.set("port", portx);  // to here

app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.use(express.static("public", __dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.get("/", function(request, response) {

  response.render("index");

});

app.post("/message", function(request, response) {

  var message = request.body.message;

  if(_.isUndefined(message) || _.isEmpty(message.trim())) {
    return response.json(400, {error: "Message is invalid"});
  }

  var name = request.body.name;
  io.sockets.emit("incomingMessage", {message: message, name: name});
  response.json(200, {message: "Message received"});
});

io.on("connection", function(socket){

  socket.on("newUser", function(data) {
    participants.push({id: data.id, name: data.name});
    io.sockets.emit("newConnection", {participants: participants});
  });

  socket.on("nameChange", function(data) {
    _.findWhere(participants, {id: socket.id}).name = data.name;
    io.sockets.emit("nameChanged", {id: data.id, name: data.name});
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    participants = _.without(participants,_.findWhere(participants, {id: socket.id}));
    io.sockets.emit("userDisconnected", {id: socket.id, sender:"system"});
  });

});

http.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("ipaddr"), function() {
  console.log("Server up and running. Go to http://" + app.get("ipaddr") + ":" + app.get("port"));
});
```

Now I get this similar error.

```
2013-09-28T02:38:51.301568+00:00 app[web.1]: info: socket.io started
2013-09-28T02:38:51.363825+00:00 app[web.1]: Server up and running. Go to http://127.0.0.1:31707
2013-09-28T02:39:50.974347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2013-09-28T02:39:50.974557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-28T02:39:52.927176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-09-28T02:39:52.945829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 8):

I can't be sure without the Node code where you create the server, however from the logs it looks like you are not listening on the correct port.

Heroku assigns your application a port (which is set as the "PORT" environment variable) that your application must listen on. If you do not connect to this port within 60s, it will kill your app, and this seems to be what is happening.

UPDATE:
In fact, based on your web.1 log entry, it looks like you are trying to listen on port 8080. I think it is highly unlikely that this is the port provided by Heroku. You can get the port Heroku provides from process.env.PORT, and then listen on that.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct, I had the port set to 8080. I didn't realize Heroku provided a specific port. I made a change to the code, replacing 8080 with process.env.PORT. I then do a $foreman start and all is well, now on port 5000, I then push to Heroku. But as soon as I start the dynos, I get the same error R10.

Comment: Can I ask why you are giving it a specific IP address?

Comment: Because that's what some tutorial told me to do.

Comment: Mhmm, I haven't seen that before. Have you tried without specifying the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

try looking in your dashboard check that you have at least one Dynos. It's happen to me that I add more than one app and I use the free trail so it keep moving the Dyno between the app.

Good Luck.