# App crashes on heroku, but works locally when I listen at port

Tags: node.js, heroku

Here is my node app `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();

const port=8000;

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('live on port '+port);
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('this is the main homepage GET response');
});
```

When I run this locally using

```
node index.js
```

it works as expected; I get a console message:

```
live on port 8000
```

and then when I open `http://localhost:8000` in my browser, I see

```
this is the main homepage GET response
```

But when I deploy to Heroku, I just get "Application error".  The same happens if I comment out the `app.listen()` and redeploy.

Heroku log for the crash shows:

```
2018-01-06T23:41:12.121338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-01-06T23:41:14.907585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2018-01-06T23:41:18.142788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-01-06T23:41:18.159613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

which isn't very informative; how can I get more precise debugging info about this crash?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19056807/619177), I used the environment variable for the port specified in `app.listen()`, and it worked:

```
const port=process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('live on port '+port);
});
```